# IBM MobileFirst platform adapter to adapter call in java doesn't support utf-8 or (arabic lang) in response

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mfp

when call adapter to adapter using AdaptersAPI in java , getting response as rabish if it contains Arabic letters.
below snippet of my code

```
HttpEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(params), 
ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON );
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);
    HttpResponse httpResp = adaptersAPI.executeAdapterRequest(httpPost);
    JSONObject response = adaptersAPI.getResponseAsJSON(httpResp);
```

Comment: Can you verify if the adapter you called is getting the response incorrectly ( from the backend that returned Arabic letters)? Or is the second adapter getting the response correctly , but when the first adapter ( calling adapter) gets the response from the second, it gets it incorrectly?

Comment: thank you @VivinK ,
second choice " the second adapter getting the response correctly , but when the first adapter ( calling adapter) gets the response from the second, it gets it incorrectly "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was found in parsing of json > `adaptersAPI.getResponseAsJSON(httpResp);`

my issue resolved by: 
 adding this property `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in "jvm.options" ,or change json parsing method